# How to not be asked every time whether to use TouchWiz Home or TouchWiz Easy Home?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, launcher, samsung-galaxy-s-3-neo

On my Samsung Galaxy SIII Neo (Android KitKat 4.4.2), as soon as I reboot the phone and enter my password to unlock the screen I get the following dialog box, asking me which home screen app I want to use. I am then asked the same question on several other occasions (such as when I exit another application, perhaps one that fires up by default when the phone starts):

[image]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>
I always click on Always, and then OK in the following screen:

[image]
<sup>Click to enlarge</sup>
The problem is that every time I reboot my phone I get asked the same question. Is there a way to permanently store this setting (and perhaps change it at a later time via the phone's Settings app)?

This seems like a bug on my particular Samsung device (since I haven't had the same problem on other Samsung phones I have tried). I wonder whether there's a way to fix it.

Comment: Can you try to disable the Launcher that you don't want to be shown? Then I think it will pick the only Launcher available as active. Also does the same happen if you select Google now Launcher?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. How do I go about disabling the launcher which I don't want to be shown? No, when I choose the Google Now Launcher this does not happen, but I do not like the Google Now Launcher, would rather use TouchWiz home. Thanks.

Comment: Go to Settings > Apps > All > Touchwiz home > Disable. If the Disable option is not selectable then you need to root your phone to disable or uninstall unwanted system apps.

Comment: But it's not TouchWiz home which I want to disable. I want to disable the app which allows choosing between `TouchWiz home`, `TouchWiz easy home`, and `Google Now Launcher`. The Google Now Launcher has an `Uninstall` button to the right of `Force stop`.  There is also a `SetDefaultLauncher` app which however has a `Force stop` button which can be clicked and a `Turn off` button which is disabled no matter what. The `TouchWIz home` and `TouchWiz easy home` apps also have a `Force stop` button which can be clicked and a `Turn off` button which is disabled no matter what.

Comment: Of course if I restart my Android OS then the apps I stopped in this way will run again.

Comment: Yes that's why I mentioned that you need to disable the unwanted Launcher app. "Force Stop" will stop working unless restarted. Apps will definitely start working after a reboot. So inorder to permamnently force stop you need to "Disable" the corresponding app. Hope its clear.

Comment: Did you read my reply? I have no `Disable` button. I only have a `Turn off` button. Also, what is the name of the app that launches the launcher. That is the app I need to "disable", because I want the TouchWiz home to be launched automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You have said that if you select Google Now launcher the problem does not happen. It sounds like Google Now is forcing the choice. If you do not use the Google Now, I would suggest uninstalling it and this should fix the problem for you.

Comment: Generally good advice anyway - If you don't use it, disable it. If possible, uninstall it.